# connection string with provider name in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use OLEDB connection string in code behind but i am getting this error: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.  I have tried to remove the provider string from the web config but get another error.  Here is the connection-string in the web config file:

```
connection string in the ASPX file:
<add name="MyNewConnection" connectionString="Provider=NZOLEDB;Data Source=KLM-netezza-1;Password=myPassword;User ID=myUser;Initial Catalog=ADMIN" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

and here is my code behind:

```
  OleDbConnection sqlcon = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyNewConnection"].ConnectionString);
    OleDbCommand sqlcmd = new OleDbCommand();

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Comment: I believe the `SqlConnection` class is for making connections to a SQL Server instance, but it looks like you're using Netezza.  Have you tried using the `OleDbConnection` class?

Comment: i have updated my code please see my initial post. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying the provider as OLEdb, but using classes from the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace (`SqlClient`, `SqlCommand`, etc).  The provider you're specifying is NOT SqlServer, so instead of using the System.Data.SqlClient classes, use the OleDb classes.  They all essentially work the same.

The SqlClient classes all assume you're using SqlServer.

Comment: @moe Take a look at my comment above - I believe Netezza requires you to use the `OleDbConnection` (and `OleDb*` classes in general) for db operations.  An example can be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9ac4a7af-6e3f-41d8-8b8e-14b707697e06/c-code-to-connect-netezza-using-oledb-provider?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: i have tried to use OledbConnection and i am getting this error: An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB

Comment: i also removed this from my webconfig: Provider=NZOLEDB

Comment: Tim, i haveupated my code please see at my initial post.  thanks

Comment: Since you're going to be using a ole provider, you need the provider specified in addition to using the System.Data.OleDb classes.  What do you get when you have both?

Comment: when i keep the provider in the web config, i get the error i menioned above but when i remove the provider from the web config then i get this error: An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString